# Django: Get request in base class

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have a base class extending object and I am trying to access self.request.session but it is throwing an error saying request doesn't exist.

```
class BaseTemplateView(object):

def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):

    try:

        if self.request.session.get('sessionToken', None) == None:
            raise ValueError("User Not Logged In")


        register(APPLICATION_ID, REST_API_KEY, session_token=token)
        self.user = User.current_user()
        self.LoggedIn = True
        print("SUCCESS")
    except:
        print("FAILED")
        self.user = None
        self.LoggedIn = False
    print("CALLED INIT")

class IndexView(BaseTemplateView, TemplateView):
      template_name = "dashboard.html"
```

Please help

Comment: Accept the answer which solvecyur problem else people think question is still open

Answer (score 0):

No, the request does not exist at that point
 This logic should go in the `dispatch` method.

Comment: where does the dispatch function go? is it in IndexView or BaseTemplateView

Comment: I don't understand your question. You define the function on your base class, whatever that is.

Comment: All my general functions are in my basetemplateview class. __init__ function verifies if a user is logged in using sessionToken which is stored in my session. If a user is not logged in, he will be redirected to the login page otherwise move on. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Not really. My answer stands: the user doesn't exist when the `__init__` method is called; this logic goes in the dispatch method.

Comment: Now that i think about it, I can pass session token from dispatch to IndexView to BaseTemplateView using super __init__. I am not really sure how to pass the value in args or kwargs

Answer (score 0):

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if self.request.session.get('sessionToken', None) == None:
                raise ValueError("User Not Logged In")
            register(APPLICATION_ID, REST_API_KEY, session_token=token)
            self.user = User.current_user()
            self.LoggedIn = True
            print("SUCCESS")
        except:
            print("FAILED")
            self.user = None
            self.LoggedIn = False
            print("CALLED INIT")
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This really defeats the purpose of having a base class. With this solution, I will have to do the same thing for every other views.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing the sessionToken via kwargs in init of the base class and did whatever I was planning to do.

```
class BaseTemplateView(object):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):


        try:

            if 'sessionToken' in kwargs:
                token = kwargs['sessionToken']
            else: 
                raise ValueError('Missing Token')

            register(APPLICATION_ID, REST_API_KEY, session_token=token)
            self.user = User.current_user()
            self.LoggedIn = True
            print("SUCCESS")
        except:
            print("FAILED")
            self.user = None
            self.LoggedIn = False
        print("CALLED INIT")

class IndexView(BaseTemplateView, TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        token = self.request.session.get('sessionToken', None)
        if  token != None:
            print("Token : {0}".format(token))
            super(IndexView, self).__init__( *args, sessionToken=token)

        if not self.isLoggedIn:
            HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope this help any newbie in django like me and not spend a day trying to figure out a very simple solution